# Is it better practice to pass sometimes complex dicts for parameters instead of parameter objects?

Tags: python, parameters, arguments

I've been programming Python for a year now, having come from a Java background, and I've noticed that, at least in my organization, the style for passing complex parameters to functions is to use dicts or tuples, rather than instances of a specialized parameter class. For example, we have a method that takes three dicts, each structured in a particular way, each of which is itself formatted as tuples. It's complicated for me to build args and to read the code. Here's an example of a passed arg:

```
{'[A].X': ((DiscreteMarginalDistribution, ('red', 'blue')), ()),
 '[A].Y': ((DiscreteConditionalDistribution, ('yellow', 'green'), ('red', 'blue')),
           (IdentityAggregator('[A].X'), ))
```

My questions are:

1. Is passing dicts/tuples like this a common Python idiom?
2. When, if ever, do you write Python code to use the latter (parameter instances)? E.g., when the nested structure surpasses some complexity threshold.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been programming in Python for about 2-3 months now and I wonder about this too... IMHO, if your dict is structured a certain way and everything will break if you add/remove a field - you might as well use a class for that. Especially in your case where dict keys are obviously field names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Yes, it is very usual to pass a dictionary to Python functions in order to reduce the number of arguments. Dictionary-style configuration with proper key naming is much more readable than just using tuples.
- I consider it rather uncommon to dynamically construct dedicated instances of a custom config class. I'd stick with dictionaries for that. In case your config dict and the consumer of it go out of sync, you get `KeyError`s, which are pretty good to debug.

**Some recommendations and reasoning:**

If some parts of your application require really really complex configuration, I consider it a good idea to have a configuration object that properly represents the current config. However, in my projects I never ended up passing such objects as function arguments. This smells. In some applications, I have a *constant* global configuration object, set up during bootstrap. Such an object is globally available and treated as "immutable".

Single functions should never be so complex that they require to retrieve a tremendously complex configuration. This indicates that you should split your code into several components, each subunit having a rather simple parameterization.

If the runtime configuration of a function has a somewhat higher complexity than it is easily dealt with normal (keyword)arguments, it is absolutely common to pass a dictionary, so to say as a "leightweight" configuration object. A well thought-through selection of key names makes such an approach very well readable. Of course you can also build up a hierarchy in case one level is not enough for your use case.

Most importantly, please note that in many cases the best way is to explicitly define the parameterization of a function via its signature, using the normal argument specification:

```
def f(a, b, c, d, e):
    ...
```

In the calling code, you can then prepare the values for these arguments in a dictionary:

```
arguments = {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
    d = 4,
    e = "x"
}
```

and then use Python's snytactic sugar for keyword expansion upon function call:

```
f(**arguments)
```

Comment: What about smaller type stuff? Like a function that draws a certain point on a graph, and takes a parameter that has: coordinates, color, additional text, etc. Wouldn't it be wise to make such a parameter an object, instead of using dict?

Comment: The first choice always is to have an explicitly defined function call signature. Especially in case you are designing a public API. This can get complex, but it is *explicit* and still easy to read. Extreme cases are, for example, the matplotlib API: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar or the pandas API: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html#pandas-io-parsers-read-csv

Comment: I agree about parameters. But there are situations where I feel dicts are used incorrectly, you see, dict is a mapping type, it maps certain values to other values, but it doesn't have to be field names, like it's often abused. I mean an object is a dict that maps field names to values, why not use objects in situations where you map strings (field names) to values? (From my shallow experience, I see it's quite common to use dicts for that)

Comment: Because Python objects introduce additional complexity over simple dictionaries. If you do not need that complexity, then why use it? More complexity than required is a bad design choice. Please do not use objects because `obj.attr` looks nicer than `d["attr"]`.

Comment: What I don't like about passing dictionaries is that the docstring can get out of sync with the parameters in the dictionary. When you explicitly define each parameter, modern IDEs remind you to update the docstring. You would loose that if you use a dictionary.